# How to access a WCF service in a virtual directory in an asp.net MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, deployment, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to deploy an asp.net MVC and a WCF service in a single website. The root site is the MVC application and i am going to run the WCF as a virtual directory of the site. However  the service cant be accessed since the routing of the MVC would not relay the request to the service. It would say "Page not Found".

http://PC:9000  <- root of mvc application

I have a virtual directory for the wcf named "wcf",

http://pc:9000/wcf/service.svc <- should have accessed the service but routes of the mvc intervened and will display page not found.

Any idea how to make this work? How would i ignore the routing if the call is for the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did:

Because the root application is an MVC, when the user tries to access the WCF in the virtual directory and try to navigate, the MVC will detect that the user is not yet authenticated in the WCF app. What the MVC will do is it will reroute it to the authentication form page as directed by the web config.

To solve this, just add the following code on the  web config file of the MVC.

```
<location path="WCF">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None">
      </authentication>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

What this means is to disable the authentication of the WCF path. So when the user access WCF service, it will not notify the MVC that WCF is not yet authenticated and thus no rerouting occurs.

This solve my problem.

Comment: Note that this requires the "WCF" path to be an application, not just a virtual directory.  See [authentication Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e.aspx) which says: "Configurable locations: Machine.config ,Root-level Web.config, Application-level Web.config".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ignore route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc");
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me. Its page not found and the URL will try to redirect to the login page.